# Swift vDSP rFFT not same as Python np.fft.rfft()

Tags: fft, python, ifft

I am trying to implement real FFT in iOS, for that i am using Accelerate Framework. Here is my Code for Swift.

```
    class FFT {

private var fftSetup: FFTSetup?
private var log2n: Float?
private var length: Int?

func initialize(count: Int){
    length = count
    log2n = log2(Float(length!))
    self.fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(vDSP_Length(log2n!), FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2))!
}

func computeFFT(input: [Float]) -> ([Float], [Float]) {
    
    var real = input
    var imag = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: input.count)
    var splitComplexBuffer = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imag)

    let halfLength = (input.count/2) + 1
    real = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: halfLength)
    imag = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: halfLength)

    // input is alternated across the real and imaginary arrays of the DSPSplitComplex structure
    splitComplexBuffer = DSPSplitComplex(fromInputArray: input, realParts: &real, imaginaryParts: &imag)

    // even though there are 2 real and 2 imaginary output elements, we still need to ask the fft to process 4 input samples
    vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup!, &splitComplexBuffer, 1, vDSP_Length(log2n!), FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

    // zrip results are 2x the standard FFT and need to be scaled
    var scaleFactor = Float(1.0/2.0)
    vDSP_vsmul(splitComplexBuffer.realp, 1, &scaleFactor, splitComplexBuffer.realp, 1, vDSP_Length(halfLength))
    vDSP_vsmul(splitComplexBuffer.imagp, 1, &scaleFactor, splitComplexBuffer.imagp, 1, vDSP_Length(halfLength))
    
    return (real, imag)
    
}

func computeIFFT(real: [Float], imag: [Float]) -> [Float]{
    
    var real = [Float](real)
    var imag = [Float](imag)
    
    var result : [Float] = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: length!)
    var resultAsComplex : UnsafeMutablePointer<DSPComplex>? = nil

    result.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
        resultAsComplex = $0.baseAddress?.bindMemory(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: 512)
    }
    
    var splitComplexBuffer = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imag)
    
    vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup!, &splitComplexBuffer, 1, vDSP_Length(log2n!), FFTDirection(FFT_INVERSE));
    
    vDSP_ztoc(&splitComplexBuffer, 1, resultAsComplex!, 2, vDSP_Length(length! / 2));
    //
    //// Neither the forward nor inverse FFT does any scaling. Here we compensate for that.
    var scale : Float = 1.0/Float(length!);
    var copyOfResult = result;
    vDSP_vsmul(&result, 1, &scale, &copyOfResult, 1, vDSP_Length(length!));
    result = copyOfResult
    
    return result
}

func deinitialize(){
    vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup)
}
```

Here is my code of Python for computing of rFFT and irFFT

```
    # calculate fft of input block
    in_block_fft = np.fft.rfft(np.squeeze(in_buffer)).astype("complex64")

# apply mask and calculate the ifft
    estimated_block = np.fft.irfft(in_block_fft * out_mask)
```

**Question**:

- **Swift**: If I compute `rFFT` for a 512 frame and apply `irFFT` to the resultant of `rFFT`, I get the same original array.
- **Python**: Same goes for Python, if I take `rFFT` and `irFFT` I get the original array in return.
- **Problem**: The problem occurs if I compare the **results of Swift `rFFT` and Python `rFFT`**. Their results are different in decimal values. Sometimes the real part is same but the imaginary is totally different.

I tried different Framework in Python like **Numpy, SciPy and TensorFlow** and their results are exactly the same (Slight different in decimal part). But when I calculate `rfft` on same input for iOS using the Swift code above, results are different.

If anybody who has experience with Accelerate Framework and holds the knowledge of FFT help me out with this one would be very helpful. I have limited knowledge of FFT.

Comment: How are they different? Scaling, peaks in different positions?

Answer (score 1):

Sanity check your data layouts.

It is very common for FFT libraries to pack the (real-valued) Nyquist-bin into the unused imaginary component of the DC-bin and it happens almost naturally when you implement a real-transform as a half-size complex-transform.

As far as I can tell, vDSP wants such "packed" layout, where as Python apparently stores it as a separate "unpacked" real-component in a larger array.